# Additional Jupyter Notebooks do not start on next available port

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When using Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10 and starting multiple notebooks, each would open on the next available port (the first would be on port 8888, the next on 8889, etc.). I installed Anaconda on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and have had no issues, except when I try to start another notebook, it opens the same page wherever my previous notebook was started. Manually setting the port on startup like `jupyter notebook --port 8889` works, but now I'm spoiled with letting jupyter figure it out for me.

I had to set an alias for the default browser, which is a Windows executable (`export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'`). Additionally, I've generated a notebook configuration file, but I haven't figured out if it's doing anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is but I may be able to help you with your config file and default browser.

The following is my `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file:

```
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'chrome.exe -incognito --app=%s'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = True
```

`chrome.exe` is the windows executable file for google chrome which is put on my `$PATH` variable as follows:
`export PATH=/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Google/Chrome/Application:$PATH`

The -incognito flag starts chrome in incognito mode. This results in the nice incognito dark theme and insures that the chrome extensions don't interfere with anything

The `--app=%s` flag is REALLY great, it starts the web page in "application mode" which removes the tab bar from the chrome window.

P.S. I'm also annoyed about the port issue and haven't found a nice work around.

Hope this helps!